# Flutter web showDialog with route(url)

Tags: flutter

I have problem with showing dialog with route setting, and I also want it to be in navigator stack just like twitter's writting tweet dialog.

> https://twitter.com/compose/tweet

I'm currently using Beamer for routing. Is there any way to achieve my goal with beamer package??

Answer (score 0):

You can show a DialogRoute in your Beamer locations as shown in this official example: https://github.com/slovnicki/beamer/blob/master/examples/books_dialogroute/lib/main.dart

```dart
BeamPage(
  routeBuilder: (
    BuildContext context,
    RouteSettings settings,
    Widget child,
  ) =>
      DialogRoute<void>(
    context: context,
    builder: (context) => child,
    settings: settings,
  ),
  key: ValueKey('book-buy-${state.pathParameters['bookId']}'),
  onPopPage: (context, delegate, _, page) {
    // when the dialog is dismissed, we only want to pop the `buy=true` query parameter
    // instead of also popping the bookId.
    delegate.currentBeamLocation.update(
      (state) => (state as BeamState).copyWith(queryParameters: {}),
    );
    return true;
  },
  child: AlertDialog(
    title: Text("Buy book"),
    actions: [],
  ),
)
```